# why the types of regular textures or texture buffer objects must be uniform in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have found all the opengl tutorials would set sampler types or TBO types as **uniform** in GLSL. But I don't know why. Could anyone explained in more details?

Comment: What do you expect it should be instead of a uniform? As input you have per vertex data (attributes)  and per call data (uniforms). What other kind of date should there be?

Comment: @ t.niese Oh, I get your idea. Thanks : )

Comment: @t.niese the samplers  could theoretically be also constant (just like we can explicitly define layout location for attributes) as the texture unit layout is usually constant but GLSL does not allow that.

Comment: @Spektre But how would that contradict that uniforms are named that way because they do not change within a particular rendering call? Or do you mean that the possibility is missing that you directly reference a sampler instead of referencing the _slot_ where the sampler is bound to, but then I don't get the layout part.

Comment: @t.niese you miss my (and asker) point texture samplers are the only variable type that can not be defined as global/local variable nor constant nor cast nor set inside GLSL can exist only as uniform even if it is in 99.9% of cases just integer constant not changing in any way during app runtime. I see no naming nor syntax conflicts nor any reason why GLSL prohibits it but it does. With TBOs you are right of coarse

Comment: @Spektre Sorry there seems to be a language barrier because I still don't get the point :) If you want to use a constant binding without setting it in the application you can write `layout(binding=0) uniform sampler2D tex;`, so it will always use the texture bound to  0?

Comment: @t.niese didn't know it could be done thx +1 for that :) ... but isn't it just location of the uniform instead of the texture unit itself?

Comment: @Spektre It's the unit where the texture is bound to. If you bind a texture to `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 4);` then `layout(binding=4) uniform sampler2D tex;` would be equivalent to `glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "tex"), 4)`

Comment: @t.niese I think you should summarize your comments into answer ...

Answer (score 1):

In GLSL you have two kind off input data. Data that can change per vertex/instance (*attributes*), and global data that stays the same through out on rendering call (*uniforms*,*buffers*).

To use a texture you bind it to a texture unit, and to use it in the shader program you will set the value of the *uniform* to the idx of the texture unit.

So a setup would look like this:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 4)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "tex"), 4)
```

Since OpenGL 4.2 you can define the binding within the shader itself so you do not need a the `glUniform1i` call if the used texture unit is known:

```
layout(binding=4) uniform sampler2D tex;
```